# Can you modify SQL DB schema in a transaction to know if all changes were applied?

Tags: sql, t-sql, transactions

As part of my (new) database version control methodology, I'm writing a "change script" and want the change script to insert a new row into the SchemaChangeLog table if the script is executed successfully, or to reverse changes if any single change in the script fails.

Is it possible to do schema changes in a transaction and only if it gets committed to then do the INSERT?

For example (psuedo-code, I'm not too good with SQL):

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION
PRINT 'Add Col2 to Table1'
IF NOT EXIST (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE NAME='Col2' AND object_id=OBJECT_ID('Table1'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
    ADD Col2 int NULL
END
INSERT INTO SchemaChangeLog(MajorVer, MinorVer, PointVer, ScriptName, AppliedDate) VALUES(N'01', N'01', N'0000', N'update.01.01.0000.sql', GETDATE())
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two actions to be atomic, embed them in a transaction. So your two actions are 1) ALTER TABLE and 2) INSERT INTO SchemaChangeLog. Therefore, your BEGIN TRANSACTION must occur before the ALTER TABLE, and the COMMIT **after** the INSERT.

As a side note, there is is an already built-in mechanism into SQL Server for tracking schema changes, it works out of the box and the best is that it will catch *everybody's* changes, not only yours: [Event Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175854.aspx).

Comment: Okay, so I do the COMMIT after, which makes sense. I just tried this and the technique does seem to work. However, I don't understand how Event Notifications helps here. I'm trying to automate, as much as possible, the updating of a database when scripts are checked out of version control.

Comment: I've done a bunch of experimentation and indeed, you can use the SET XACT_ABORT ON feature and wrap your schema changes in a transaction and simply attempt to do the SchemaChangeLog table insertion right before committing, and everything will work as expected. No need for Event Notification. Marking this as answer to avoid writing my own answer (not professional).